# Difference between /opt/bin and /opt/X/bin directories

Tags: package-management, directory-structure, fhs

The `/opt/` directory in Linux is used for installing add on packages.

What is the difference between the `/opt/<package>/bin` directory and the `/opt/<package>/X/bin` directory? What is the difference between placing the binary in these directories?

Could you also please point me to some documentation which explains what the directory structure should be for a new software package/application installed in the `/opt/` directory?

Comment: Wait, was @Stephen Kitt's edit what you actually meant? You seemed previously to be asking about `/opt/bin` (which I've seen) vs. `/opt/package/bin`, but now it looks like you're asking about `/opt/package/X/bin`, which I haven't seen in any package...

Comment: @Bandrami, my edit just revealed what @arun had typed originally; the `<package>` portions of the paths were interpreted as HTML tags. So the original input, `/opt/<package>/bin`, appeared as /opt//bin, and `/opt/<package>/X/bin` appeared as /opt//X/bin.

Answer (score 5):

[Per FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-3.12.html), `/opt/bin`, `/opt/lib`, `/opt/info`, `/opt/include`, `/opt/doc`, and `/opt/man` are there for the administrator's convenience. For instance, you might have `/opt/jdk` and `/opt/LibreOffice` holding your jdk and office suite, but rather than add a new element to `$PATH`, `ld.so.conf`, etc. every time you add another package, you can just symlink the binaries to `/opt/bin`, the libs to `/opt/lib`, etc.

Basically, you should put the binary in `/opt/foo/bin` and, at your discretion, symlink the binary into `/opt/bin`

FHS does not specify any particular organization within `/opt/package`, but the widely accepted practice is to make a `bin` and `lib` directory, and possibly `doc`, `man`, etc. as needed.

As a side note: if you are writing to `/opt/foo` FHS also clears you to write to `/etc/opt/foo` and `/var/opt/foo`.