# How should executables installed under /opt be added to the path?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-installation, directory-structure, fhs

Can programs installed under `/opt` be safely symlinked into `/usr/local/bin`, which is already in the PATH by default in Ubuntu and other Linux distros?

Alternatively, is there some reason to create a separate `/opt/bin` and add that to the PATH, as in this answer: [Difference between /opt/bin and /opt/X/bin directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198071/difference-between-opt-bin-and-opt-x-bin-directories)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a difference between `/opt` and `/usr/local/bin`. So just symlinking binaries from one to another would be confusing. I would not mix them up.

`/opt` is for the installation of *add-on application software packages*, whereas the `/usr/local` directory is for the *system administrator when installing software locally* (with `make` and `make install`). `/usr/local/bin` is intended for binaries from software installed under `/usr/local`.

According to the [File Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES), the correct way would be to add `/opt/<package>/bin` to the `$PATH` for each individual package. If this is too painful (when you have an uncountable number of `/opt/<package>/bin` direcories for example) then you (the local administrator) can create symlinks from `/opt/<package>/bin` to the `/opt/bin` directory. This can then be added to the users `$PATH` once.

Comment: Eh, why? `/usr/local/bin` is for the system administrator's use. If the admin wants to install software in `/opt` and create links for it under `/usr/local`, that's perfectly cromulent.

Comment: @Gilles Of course he can, he can do whatever he wants, he's the system administrator. But best practice would be to keep them separate.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like this is more an issue of standard convention than anything else. I was a bit weirded out by the lack of symmetry "There is a difference between `/opt` and `/usr/local/bin`" as opposed to than "...between `/opt` and `/usr/local`" or "...between `/opt/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`", but after getting to the end I suspect it was meant as a way to combine `/opt/bin` and `/opt/.../bin`. If so, I wonder if the wording could be improved.

Comment: @chaos You write that, according to FHS, `/opt/package/bin/` or at least `/opt/bin/` should be added to $PATH. I read through the posted reference and it does say a lot about how to structure `/opt`and what to have inside there but I could not find a confirmation that any of those directories under `/opt` should be added to $PATH. Could you maybe elaborate how you came to that conclusion? Cheers

Comment: @vic The same reason you would put any other `/whatever/bin` directory to $PATH -- so you can invoke the executables without typing the full path every time.

Comment: @KennethHanson Nah, I kind of agree with vic, the way FHS is worded, it seems that the intended behavior is to add /opt/bin to the path, and symlink the /opt/package/bin to it.

Comment: @DidierA. Maybe I was misreading vic, but it sounded like he was questioning whether anything should be added to $PATH at all. The FHS says basically nothing about $PATH in general (you can ctrl-F to see), so I wouldn't try too hard to divine the authors' assumptions. Strictly speaking, they are separate issues. That said, I agree that adding just `/opt/bin` seems to be the most sensible default choice.

Comment: @KennethHanson Ya, fair enough. I guess they do mention that /opt/bin can be used for " Packages may provide "front-end" files intended to be placed in (by linking or copying) these reserved directories by the local system administrator". Which sounds to me like they imply that /opt/bin is only to be used for that purpose. But obviously, you can also add each /opt/package/bin to your path if you prefer.

Comment: When you say `/opt/<package>/bin`, I guess you meant `/opt/<package>/<bin>` because on software like Firefox, there is nothing named "bin" and the executable will be `/opt/firefox/firefox`.