# How to call a binary outside PATH

Tags: linux, directory-structure

I recently downloaded Master PDF Editor. It's a proprietary software for Linux and the archive contained bascically only a *.desktop file and the actual binary.

Looking at the *.desktop file, the binary is supposed to be placed in `/opt/master-pdf-editor-3`. I'm aware I could change that but I followed the suggestion. Naturally, I still cannot call the binary on its own since it's not in my PATH.

I can think of several solutions. I could add the binary path to PATH, I could create a (soft or hard) link inside a folder that already is in PATH, such as `/usr/bin`, or I could write a shell script in the same place that will call the binary.

I was wondering, is there some sort of commonly accepted best practice or rule when to use one over the other?

If it matters, I'm on Arch Linux.

P.S. [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248029/how-should-executables-installed-under-opt-be-added-to-the-path) is very similar but the focus there is on the directory structure and not on the different possibilities how to call the binary itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a hardlink should probably be avoided, there's no need for one and a symlink is simpler and safer. Your other solutions are also fine though. You can create as script that calls the binary or you can add the directory to your `PATH`. The latter might be preferable if you expect to add other binaries in `/opt` as well.

This is essentially a matter of preference. In such cases, usually the simplest solution is the best. So, just create a soft link and you're all set:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/master-pdf-editor-3 /usr/bin
```

Alternatively, of course, you could just call the binary with its full path:

```
/opt/master-pdf-editor-3
```

Finally, if it's only for your user, you can create an alias by adding this line to your shell's initialization file (e.g. `~/.bashrc`):

```
alias master-pdf-editor-3='/opt/master-pdf-editor-3'
```

Anyway, no, there isn't any single Best Way© to do this. It depends on how you want your system to be set up and your own preferences as the system's administrator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you maybe elaborate on just one thing. When would you prefer a soft link over of a shell script, and vice versa? BTW, the binary is in the package subfolder of /opt, so you would have to add each package separately to the path which seems messy.

Comment: @vic personally, I would always go for the softlink. It's easier and doesn't require the creation of a script. AFAIK, there's no hard technical reason to chose one over the other. I would only use a wrapper script if I always wanted to call a program with certain options/parameters set. As I said though, do what you prefer. I find softlinks to be cleaner, simpler and more elegant than creating wrapper scripts. And yes, if they're in subfolders of `/opt` (which makes sense) it's more of a pain to add them to PATH.